# How to filter pending changelist by changelist number

Tags: p4v, changelist

Using p4V client I want to review pending changelist with shelved files. I have the changelist number but can't find a way to filter based on changelist number.

I found out about using Ctrl-G to search for pending changelist. However that does not give me an option to unshelve.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the "Unshelve..." command in the context menu of the files in the "Shelved Files" list.